# Camera Preview starts to lag when adding GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

In my application i have the following layout (simplified):

```
+---------------+
| CameraPreview |
|               |
+---------------+
| GLSurf.View   |
|               |
+---------------+
```

At the top I have a SurfaceView showing a live preview of the camera.
At the bottom there is a GLSurfaceView rendering some openGL stuff.

I noticed that as soon as I add the GLSurfaceView to the layout, the camera preview is slower, i.e. there is a lag of quite a couple of ms.

Does anyone has an idea why this is the case?
Also, i noticed that when I increase the camera preview size to a size that is greater than the Surface View, I can see the overlapping section of the camera preview in the GLSurfaceView which is quite strange.

Comment: Do the SurfaceView and GLSurfaceView have the same z-order?  If so, the contents of an overlapping region are undefined.  What device are you testing on?  You can use `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` to see the window size / position / Z order.  See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html if none of that is familiar.

Comment: Configuring a preview SurfaceView to follow exactly the layout may be a challenge, especially when the aspect ratio is not preserved.

Comment: Regarding the delay, if the device is single-core, there is little you can do about it. If the device has at least 2 cores, you can try to bring the preview and the OpenGL to separate threads.

Comment: @fadden I've tried to call ``setZOrderOnTop(true)`` on the camera surface view. It seems that it makes things a little bit better (although I don't know if it's just better by accident). Is it possible, from your experience, that this has solved my problem?

Comment: @AlexCohn How would I bring the preview and the OpenGL surface to seperate threads? Is it simply by instantiating these things in a different Thread? (Note: I'm already opening my camera instance from a different looper thread)

Comment: I don't exactly understand your problem yet. Is your screen split in two panes, or you use "top" to describe the z-order?

Comment: It's nice to launch camera in a separate Looper, but this is not a _panacea_. The Looper helps to receive preview callbacks in a separate thread, this resolves nasty lags and jitter when using `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` in e.g. video chat scenario. But the preview surface refreshes itself in a different thread anyway (it is controlled by the system; you can easily prove it: pop up a dialog and perform a sleep on the UI thread: the camera preview will continue live regardless).

Comment: But the OpenGL thread is different: it is created by the system, and you are supposed to perform drawing - and only drawing - on that thread. Therefore, if you have some processing to do for the OpenGL display, you should do that on a separate thread.

Comment: I would rather try to switch to SurfaceTexture technique, and display both "views" (textures) on the same one big GL surface.